# How to build up test cases in junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm coming from a Perl background where I used `Test::More` to handle unit testing. Using that framework, I knew the order in which the tests took place and could rely on that, which I understand is not encouraged with the JUnit framework. I've seen several ways to get around this, but I want to understand the proper/intended way of doing things.

In my Perl unit testing I would build up tests, knowing that if test #3 passed, I could make some assumptions in further tests. I don't quite see how to structure that in the JUnit world so that I can make every test completely independent.

For example, suppose I have a class that parses a date from a string. Methods include:

- parse a simple date (YYYY-MM-DD)
- parse a simple date with alternate separator (YYYY_MM_DD or YYYY/MM/DD)
- parse a date with a string for a month name (YYYY-MON-DD)
- parse a date with a string month name in a different language
- and so on

I usually write my code to focus as many of the externally-accessible methods into as few core methods as possible, re-using as much code as possible (which is what most of us would do, I'm sure). So, let's say I have 18 different tests for the first method, 9 that are expected to pass and 9 that throw an exception. For the second method, I only have 3 tests, one each with the separators that work ('_' & '/') and one with a separator that doesn't work ('*') which is expected to fail. I can limit myself to the new code being introduced because I already know that the code properly handles the standard boundary conditions and common errors, because the first 18 tests already passed.

In the Perl world, if test #20 fails, I know that it's probably something to do with the specific separator, and is not a general date parsing error because all of those tests have already passed. In the JUnit world, where tests run in a random order, if test #20 fails, I don't know if it's because of a general date parsing issue or because of the separator. I'd have to go and see which other ones failed and then make some assumptions there. That's not too hard to do, of course, but maybe in a bigger, more complex class, it would be more difficult to do.

How do other people deal with building up a set of tests? Should I put each and every test in a separate class and use a test suite? That seems tedious. (And before someone suggests that I put the first18 in one class and the second 3 in another, and use a test suite for just those groupings, let's pretend that all 18 of the early tests build on each other, too).

And, again, I know there are ways around this (FixedMethodOrder in JUnit 4.11+ or JUnit-HierarchicalContextRunner) but I want to understand the paradigm as its intended to be used.

Comment: You can't assume anything about the order the tests are executed in.  Some runners run in different order than others.  Usually people use one test class per code class.  If you have tests that throw exceptions you mark them as such and they will succeed, for example.  @Test(expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In the JUnit world, where tests run in a random order, if test #20 fails, I don't know if it's because of a general date parsing issue or because of the separator. I'd have to go and see which other ones failed and then make some assumptions there.**

Yes that is correct.  If something in your code is broken then multiple tests may fail.  That is a good thing.  Use intent revealing test method names and possibly use the optional String message parameter in the JUnit assertions to explain what exactly failed the test.

**How do other people deal with building up a set of tests? Should I put each and every test in a separate class and use a test suite?**

The general convention is one test class per source class.  Depending on what build tool you are using, you may or may not need to use test suites.  If you are using Ant, you probably need to collect the tests into test suites, but if you are using Maven, the test plugins for maven will find all your test classes for you so you don't need suites.

I also want to point out that you should be coding to Java interfaces as much as possible.  If you are testing class `C` that depends on an implementation of interface `I`, then you should mock your `I` implementation in your `C` test class so that `C` is tested in isolation.  Your mock `I` should follow what the interface is **supposed** to do.  This also keeps the number of failing tests down.  If there is a bug in your real `I` implementation, then only your `I` tests should fail, the `C` tests should still all pass (since you are testing it against a fake but working `I` implementation)

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about suites yet.  You'll know when you need them.  I've only had to use them a handful of times, and I'm not entirely sold on their usefulness...but I leave that decision up to you.

To the meat of your question - the conventional way with JUnit tests is to neither know nor depend on the order of execution of your tests; this ensures that your tests are not run-order dependent, and if they are, something is wrong with your tests* and validation.

The main core concept behind unit tests is that they test a **unit of code** - as simple as a single function.  If you're attempting to test five different things at once, your test is far too large, and should be broken out.  If the method you're testing is monolithic in nature, and difficult to test, it should be refactored and broken out into different slices of responsibility.

Tests that exercise a larger flow are better suited for integration-style tests, which *tend* to be written as unit tests, but aren't *actually* unit tests.

I've not run into a scenario in which, if I knew that if a certain test failed, I could expect different behavior in the other tests.  I've never thought that such a thing was necessary to be noted, since the only thing I care about in my unit test is how *that* unit of code behaves given a certain input.

Keep your tests small and simple to understand; the test should only make one assertion about the result (or a general assertion of the state of your result).

<sup>*: That's not to say that it's completely *broken*, but those sorts of tests should be fixed sooner rather than later.</sup>

Comment: Well, that's sort of my point: keep tests as small as possible. That's why I have 18 tests for the first method, because each one tests a single assumption or edge case or error condition. So when my test that only checks whether or not I can use a '_' as a separator instead of a '-' is run, and it fails, how do I know that it's because there's a problem in the separator code and not a general number-parsing error? Obviously if everything works, I don't care in what order they execute, but when something goes wrong then knowing that earlier tests succeeded gives me a clue as to where to look.

Comment: Maybe I just need to not worry too much about when things fail, since (if I'm doing my job correctly) that won't happen too often, and I can then afford the extra time to figure out what's broken, where.

Comment: You would know it's a problem in the separator code since, ideally, that's exclusively what you're testing.  If you're not just testing that piece of code, then as stated, your test is too broad.